# How to translate "I spent three weeks relaxing on the beaches" into Spanish

Tags: traducción

Could somebody please translate "I spent three weeks relaxing on the beaches" into Spanish using the verb pasar for spent? eg.pasaría

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct translation of "I spent three weeks relaxing on the beaches" would be

> (Yo) pasé tres semanas relajándome en las playas

The "Yo" is optional since in Spanish you have what's called "Sujeto tácito" where you dont need to put the subject every single time.

Let me explain "*relajándome*". "*Relajando*" is the participle form of "*Relajar*". Furthermore, we use the "me" at the end to imply something like "(to) myself"

Pay attention to the accent marks. "*relajándome*" has the stress in the third-to-last syllable. That's why it has an accent mark (for accents, we count the syllables backwards).
Here's a brief resume of accents:

**Stress in the first (last) syllable:**

- The word ends in "n", "s" or vowel: use an accent
  mark
- The word doesn't end in "n", "s" or vowel: don't use an accent
  mark

**Stress in the second-to-last syllable:**

- The word ends in "n", "s" or vowel: don't use an accent
  mark
- The word doesn't end in "n", "s" or vowel: use an accent
  mark

**Stress in the third-to-last or fourth-to-last syllable:**

- Always use an accent mark

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the verb "pasé" is the one used to represent the past tense of "pasar". In this way, your sentence is translated to the following:

> Yo pasé tres semanas relajándome en las playas.

Comment: Are -ing words not meant to end in -ando or -iendo?

Comment: why the -dome ending?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious. If *relaxing* is intended to be used as an adjective, the translation could be

> Pasé tres semanas *relajantes* en las playas.

Else, we'll need to introduce an object pronoun when using *relaxing* in its continuous form. Here's why:

> Pasé tres semanas *relajando* en las playas.

Relaxing what? Hence, we need the object pronoun to refer to the subject:

> Pasé tres semanas *relajándome* en las playas.

Comment: Wouldn't the first thing be "three relaxing weeks" rather than "three weeks relaxing"? How could "relaxing" in "I spent three weeks relaxing on the beaches" be an adjective?